# Using .htaccess, How to force HTTPS without conflicting with other RewriteRules?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have several redirect directives in my .htaccess file, I'm redirecting all calls to the root folder to the /Site folder, it's working fine.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect index in root to index in Site folder
RewriteRule ^index\.php$  /Site/index.php [PT]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/Site
RewriteRule ^(/?)(.*) /Site/$2
```

What I need now is to force https on all of the pages, when I added the following directives, it didn't work, I believe it went into an infinite loop:

```
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
#RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

What are the right directives to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding the following after RewriteEngine On

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

For some reason

```
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
```

did not work